# How can i 4th-order BPF analysis please

Tags: filter, active-filter

[image]

How can i calculation center frequency?, and Q-factor and BW?

please detail analysis

Comment: Maybe at some point in the production of the formula you could have split it into two 2nd order filters that are cascaded.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple method for finding the center frequency \$f_o\$:

- We know that the phase crosses the 0 deg line at \$f=f_o\$. That means: The transfer function is REAL at \$f=f_o\$ (\$w=w_o\$).
- In the following we set \$s=jw\$.
- The numerator \$N(jw)\$ of the transfer function is real for \$w=w_o\$. For this reason, the denominator \$D(jw)\$ will also be real for \$w=w_o\$.
- Therefore, we set the imaginary part of \$D(jw)=0\$. This is a simple third-order equation of the form \$-A(w_o)^3+B_w=0\$ which can be reduced to \$-A(w_o)^2+B=0\$.
- Hence: \$w_o=\sqrt{\frac{B}{A}}\$

**EDIT:** Bandwidth BW and quality factor Q are related to each other (involved calculation): Q=fo/BW.

Comment: Dean , thank you for editing (inproving expressions). Did you notice the small error in the third line from the bottom (Bw)?